# Why won't CSS 'overflow-x' and 'overflow-y' work on box-shadows? Is this a bug?

Tags: css

I'm not sure whether this is an implementation bug or I'm misunderstanding how `box-shadow` relates to `overflow-x` and `overflow-y`. I'm guessing it's not a bug because I can confirm this on Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.

`box-shadow` seems to be all-or-nothing when it comes to the `overflow` property. `overflow: hidden` works on box-shadows, `overflow: visible` works too... But

```
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: visible;
```

... does not work. The browser simply hides both the x and y-axes. Expected behavior, in my opinion, would be that the box-shadow on the x-axis is hidden while the box-shadow on the y-axis is visible.

Here's what I mean, as well as a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zBqVeW):

```css
body {padding: 0; margin: 0;}.container {background: dimgray;display: flex;align-items: center;justify-content: center;width: 100vw;height: 100vh;}

.orangeSquare {
  background: orange;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: visible; /* why doesn't this work? */
 
}

.tealRectangle {
  background: teal;
  color: white;
  width: 92px;
  height: 92px;
  line-height: 92px;
  text-align: center;
  
  box-shadow: 0 0 85px 15px black;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='orangeSquare'>
    <span class='tealRectangle'>—</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas as to why this is happening? Or am I missing something obvious? A workaround would be appreciated as well. Thanks!

Comment: Considering that box shadows themselves cannot be applied to a single side (i.e. CSS does not have `box-shadow-left`, `-right`, etc. properties) I wouldn't expect it to be able to handle the scenario you have provided. How do you hide half a shadow? Does the shadow fade into the hidden region? Does it just get clipped abruptly?

Comment: @Quantastical that's a good point, I suppose the lack of `box-shadow-left` points to how tricky it might be. I just figured since it abruptly clips the box-shadow when `overflow: hidden` is set, it could replicate that functionality along the X- or Y-axis. Wishful thinking on my part I guess.

Answer (score 4):

A simple workaround for a box shadow on a single side is to add a positioned pseudo-element with a gradient background which fades to transparent.

e.g. for a shadow below (add cross-browser gradient stuff)

```css
.cropped-shadow {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 5; 
 background: #fc0;
 height: 70px;
}

.cropped-shadow:after {
 content:" ";
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 top: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 height: 10px;
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="cropped-shadow"></div>
```